# React Native send but Spring Boot don't display messages WebSocket

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, websocket, server, spring-websocket

I want to send a string from React Native to Spring Boot with the help of web sockets, but the meesage isn't displaying in Spring Boot.

**REACT NATIVE CODE**:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { RTCView, mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc';

const CameraScreen = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [audioStream, setAudioStream] = useState(null);
  var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.14:9091/audio');

  useEffect(() => {

    Voip();
  },);

  ws.onopen = () => {
    // connection opened
    console.log("opened!!");
    ws.send('something');  // send a message
  };

  ws.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  };

  async function Voip(){
    try {
      const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false });
      setAudioStream(stream);
      // if (audioStream) {
      //   console.log('Audio Stream:', audioStream);
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting user media:', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Audio Screen</Text>
      {audioStream && (
      <RTCView
        streamURL={audioStream.toURL()}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
      />
    )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default CameraScreen;

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
  },
};
```

In the react native code we can see that I am trying to send the messsages to the 192.168.1.14:9091/audio
It connects successfully, so I think it's fine from here.

**SPRING BOOT WEB SOCKET CONFIG**

```java
package infili.findTeam.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/audio");
    }
}
```

**SPRING BOOT CONTROLLER**

```java
package infili.findTeam.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    @MessageMapping("/audio")
    public void processMessage(String message) {
        // Your WebSocket message handling logic here
        System.out.println("message");
    }
}
```

**SPRING BOOT MAIN FILE**

```java
package infili.findTeam;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"infili.findTeam.repositories"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "infili.findTeam.configuration",
        "infili.findTeam.controller",
        "infili.findTeam.entity",
        "infili.findTeam.service",
        "infili.findTeam.util",
        "infili.findTeam.filters"})
public class findTeam {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(findTeam.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("(?!/error).+"))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiDetails());
    }


    private ApiInfo apiDetails() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Find Team")
                .description("Utilise API services within MyCoach")
                .version("0.1")
                .build();
    }
}
```

I tried so many things, nothing worked.